# EGlib 2.6.20 does not install (trying to install SCIP)

Tags: installation, scip

I am trying to solve an integer linear program using SCIP. The beta version that I require (for exact solving) is given at:

http://scip.zib.de/#exact

As linked there, the source code is at:

http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scip-3.0.0-ex.tgz

I followed the INSTALL file. It requires the installation of EGlib 2.6.20. However, this installation fails during 'make' with the following error:

```
phani@OptiPlex-9030-AIO ~/EGlib-2.6.20 $ make  
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/phani/EGlib-2.6.20'  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/phani/EGlib-2.6.20'  
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/phani/EGlib-2.6.20'  
Building include/EGlib.h  
Compiling src/eg_bit.c  
Compiling src/eg_compare.c  
Compiling src/eg_io.c  
src/eg_io.c: In function ‘EGioGets’:  
src/eg_io.c:618:7: warning: unused variable ‘b’ [-Wunused-variable]  
  char*b = buf;  
       ^  
src/eg_io.c: In function ‘EGioEof’:  
src/eg_io.c:648:6: warning: unused variable ‘err’ [-Wunused-variable]  
  int err;  
      ^  
src/eg_io.c: In function ‘EGmvar’:  
src/eg_io.c:42:2: warning: second parameter of ‘va_start’ not last named argument [-Wvarargs]  
  va_start (largs, nind);  
  ^  
Compiling src/eg_lpnum.c  
Compiling src/eg_net.c  
Compiling src/eg_random.c  
Compiling src/eg_macros.c  
Compiling src/eg_ehash.c  
Compiling src/eg_perm_it.c  
Compiling src/eg_symtab.c  
Compiling src/eg_keytab.c  
Compiling src/eg_simula.c  
In file included from src/eg_simula.c:25:0:  
src/eg_simula.h:227:2: error: unknown type name ‘dbl_EGeHeapCn_t’  
  dbl_EGeHeapCn_t heap_cn;/**< connector in the heap containing the agent */  
  ^  
src/eg_simula.h:240:2: error: unknown type name ‘dbl_EGeHeap_t’  
  dbl_EGeHeap_t hp; /**< Heap containing events to be processed */  
  ^  
src/eg_simula.c: In function ‘EGsimExp’:  
src/eg_simula.c:29:30: warning: unused parameter ‘t’ [-Wunused-parameter]  
 double EGsimExp(const double t, void*const data)  
                              ^  
src/eg_simula.c: In function ‘EGsimUniform’:  
src/eg_simula.c:40:34: warning: unused parameter ‘t’ [-Wunused-parameter]  
 double EGsimUniform(const double t, void*const data)  
                                  ^  
src/eg_simula.c: In function ‘EGsimNormal’:  
src/eg_simula.c:51:33: warning: unused parameter ‘t’ [-Wunused-parameter]  
 double EGsimNormal(const double t, void*const data)  
                                 ^  
In file included from src/eg_simula.c:25:0:  
src/eg_simula.c: In function ‘EGsimNewEvent’:  
src/eg_simula.h:277:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dbl_EGeHeapCnInit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
  dbl_EGeHeapCnInit(&(__EGsimA->heap_cn));\  
  ^  
src/eg_simula.c:73:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘EGsimSetAgent’  
  EGsimSetAgent(la,sim->cur_time + gen->gen(sim->cur_time,gen->data));  
  ^  
src/eg_simula.c:74:13: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
  la->heap_cn.val = la->last_time;  
             ^  
src/eg_simula.c:77:12: error: request for member ‘sz’ in something not a structure or union  
  if(sim->hp.sz == sim->hp.max_sz)   
            ^  
src/eg_simula.c:77:26: error: request for member ‘max_sz’ in something not a structure or union  
  if(sim->hp.sz == sim->hp.max_sz)   
                          ^  
src/eg_simula.c:78:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dbl_EGeHeapResize’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
   dbl_EGeHeapResize(&(sim->hp),sim->hp.sz*2);  
   ^  
src/eg_simula.c:78:39: error: request for member ‘sz’ in something not a structure or union  
   dbl_EGeHeapResize(&(sim->hp),sim->hp.sz*2);  
                                       ^  
src/eg_simula.c:80:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dbl_EGeHeapAdd’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
  rval = dbl_EGeHeapAdd(&(sim->hp),&(la->heap_cn));  
         ^  
In file included from src/eg_simula.h:47:0,  
                 from src/eg_simula.c:25:  
src/eg_simula.c:85:55: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
  MESSAGE(EG_SIM_VERBOSE,"new Agent at %lf",la->heap_cn.val);  
                                                       ^  
src/eg_macros.h:246:18: note: in definition of macro ‘MESSAGE’  
   fprintf(stderr,__VA_ARGS__);\  
                  ^  
In file included from src/eg_simula.h:47:0,  
                 from src/eg_simula.c:25:  
src/eg_simula.c: In function ‘EGsim’:  
src/eg_simula.c:284:22: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dbl_EGeHeapGetMin’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
   ca = EGcontainerOf(dbl_EGeHeapGetMin(&(sim->hp)), EGsimAgent_t,heap_cn);  
                      ^  
src/eg_macros.h:134:56: note: in definition of macro ‘EGcontainerOf’  
  typeof(((__type *)0)->__member) *const __EGcOf_ptr = (__ptr);\  
                                                        ^  
src/eg_macros.h:134:55: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]  
  typeof(((__type *)0)->__member) *const __EGcOf_ptr = (__ptr);\  
                                                       ^  
src/eg_simula.c:284:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘EGcontainerOf’  
   ca = EGcontainerOf(dbl_EGeHeapGetMin(&(sim->hp)), EGsimAgent_t,heap_cn);  
        ^  
src/eg_simula.c:285:30: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
   sim->cur_time = ca->heap_cn.val;   
                              ^  
src/eg_simula.c:327:17: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
      na->heap_cn.val = sim->cur_time + cn->gen(sim->cur_time,cn->data);  
                 ^  
src/eg_simula.c:328:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dbl_EGeHeapSiftUp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
      dbl_EGeHeapSiftUp(&(sim->hp),&(na->heap_cn));  
      ^  
src/eg_simula.c:365:17: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
      ca->heap_cn.val = sim->cur_time;  
                 ^  
src/eg_simula.c:371:17: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
      ca->heap_cn.val = sim->cur_time + nn->gen(sim->cur_time,nn->data);  
                 ^  
src/eg_simula.c:377:17: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
      ca->heap_cn.val = DBL_MAX;  
                 ^  
src/eg_simula.c:381:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dbl_EGeHeapSiftDown’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
     rval = dbl_EGeHeapSiftDown(&(sim->hp),&(ca->heap_cn));  
            ^  
src/eg_simula.c:388:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dbl_EGeHeapDel’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
     dbl_EGeHeapDel(&(sim->hp),&(ca->heap_cn));  
     ^  
src/eg_simula.c:429:17: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
      ca->heap_cn.val = sim->cur_time;  
                 ^  
src/eg_simula.c:433:17: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
      ca->heap_cn.val = sim->cur_time + nn->gen(sim->cur_time,nn->data);  
                 ^  
src/eg_simula.c:441:17: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union  
      ca->heap_cn.val = DBL_MAX;  
                 ^  
Makefile.library:38: recipe for target 'obj/eg_simula.o' failed  
make[1]: *** [obj/eg_simula.o] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/phani/EGlib-2.6.20'  
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'library' failed  
make: *** [library] Error 2
```

After some searching, I have noticed that dbl_EGeHeap_t is not defined in the source code, and that seems to be throwing errors.

On searching online, it seems to be the case that it was defined in EGlib 2.6.15 (https://conexo.dii.uchile.cl/SVN/EGlib/EGlib2/tags/EGlib-2.6.15/TEmplate/dbl_eg_eheap.h), but the corresponding file in 2.6.20 does not have the definition.

Has anybody else experienced this? I badly need a solution to this.